# Registering users with Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Does the Graph API support the creation of users with existing Microsoft Accounts and/or users in other Microsoft Azure AD directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Graph API requires you to provide a **passwordProfile** when creating new users in your directory, which would not be applicable in cases like this where your user is an external user.  There may be other properties that prevent you from doing this, but this is the biggest one IMO.

As you probably know, this is possible to do from the Azure Management portal. If you trace this using Fiddler you will notice there are some other API's the portal uses behind the scenes that are not part of the Graph API's.

Comment: Adding external users (either MSAs or users from other AAD tenants) through the Graph API is not currently supported.  It is something we want to add, but I can't give you a timeframe for this yet.  What is your scenario for this?